# Converting function to lambda expression

Tags: python, lambda

I have a python function which I would like to transform into lambda function. Someone can help me?

I'm working with Python 3.7.3 and I have a list which I want to check if this list contains a specific value stored into a var.

```
def Check(var_check, list_to_check):
    check=0
    for i in list_to_check:
        if var_check == i:
            check=1
    return(check)
```

If it's found the `var_check` into `list_to_check` I expect to return `check=1`, if is not, `return check=0`.

Comment: `lambda x: x in list_to_check`. It's pointless iterating the whole list, just use `in`. If it needs to be an `int`, use `int(x in list_to_check)`. Of course, I have no idea how you're trying to apply this function or whether `list_to_check` is available, or why you want a `lambda` in the first place

Comment: Why do you need it as lambda?  How are you going to use it?

Comment: Perfect! It works! Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
lambda var_check, list_to_check: ([0] + [1 for item in list_to_check if item == var_check])[-1]
```

Comment: Instead of providing only a code snippet, it would be helpful to describe how / why your suggestion solves the problem.